# Comparing 2 strings and parametrizing them perl

Tags: perl, math, expression

```
$s1 = 'c1 n1 n2 c = 44.3 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * 0.836
$s2 = 'c1 n1 n2 c = 41.8 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * 0.744
```

The output needs to be ($s1 is the reference, so, $s2 gives the output here)

```
c1 n1 n2 c = param1 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * param2
.param1 41.8
.param2 0.744
```

So, basic idea, is, numbers that change between the strings should be parametrized..

---------- any thoughts will be great --------

My intended solution right now (looking for something more elegant/better) :

parametrize completely in the beginning - that is, make the string look like

```
c1 n1 n2 c= param0 + ( w - param1 ) * ( l - param2 ) * param3
```

And then reinstate the numbers that don't change and then re-number the params

```
$count = 0
@params = ();
while( $s2 =~ s/(?<!\w)((?:[0-9.]{2,}|[0-9]+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)/param$count/ ){
    push( @params, $1);
    $count++;
}
```

Then you do the same for $s1, creating another array (say) @ref_params.
Then a for-loop to compare and reinstate non-changing numbers..

Answer (score 0):

This will work assuming that your strings are space delimited, but you can adjust the split to work on operators and groupings as well.

The problem is really quite simple: simultaneously iterate over the two strings word by word, when a difference is encountered convert it a parameter and note the value from `s2`.

```
sub parameterize {
    my @s1 = split /\s+/, shift;
    my @s2 = split /\s+/, shift;

    die "strings have different lengths" unless $#s1 == $#s2;

    my @out; 
    my @params;
    for (my $i=0; $i <= $#s1; $i++) {
        if ( $s1[$i] eq $s2[$i] ) {
            $out[$i] = $s1[$i];
        } else {
            push @params, $s2[$i];
            $out[$i] = 'param' . ($#params + 1);
        }
    }

    return join(' ', @out), map(".param@{[ $_+1 ]} $params[$_]", 0..$#params);
}

my $s1 = 'c1 n1 n2 c = 44.3 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * 0.836';
my $s2 = 'c1 n1 n2 c = 41.8 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * 0.744';
print join("\n", parameterize( $s1, $s2 )),"\n";
```

---

```
c1 n1 n2 c = param1 + ( w - 2 ) * ( l - 0.5 ) * param2
.param1 41.8
.param2 0.744
```